# I can't Access facebook Pages(account) details php sdk 4.0

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want get my facebook page details. I am  using php sdk 4.0 and facebook documentation gives

```
 /* PHP SDK v4.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/me/accounts'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

but After running this code 
My output is

```
Facebook\GraphObject Object ( [backingData:protected] => Array ( ) )
```

so If i miss anything in my code Or any other things

Thanks

Comment: Have you set the access_token properly? try using a simple file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=XXXXX");

See if this works or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution using facebook extended profile management

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

You can do this if you are using Facebook, connect by passing scope=email   in the get string of your call then to the Auth Dialog.

It is in the Facebook doccumentation

Answer (score 1):

If you use a test app (the main app was not submitted for fb review) you should use the test account to make request. On real account will give you an empty object/array.
More info 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps
Read about test apps and test users.